# Time difference reset by group ID

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I am having an issue finding time differences within a data frame. The following code will output the time difference between each row in the dataset. I am trying to have the time difference reset by ID. So that I will only see the differences between the same IDs. Can anyone guide me to documentation or give me some tips on how I can achieve this?

```
Golden['TimeDiff'] = Golden.CREATED_ON.diff().dt.total_seconds()
>>> Golden  
        ID          CREATED_ON             TimeDiff
        2       2014-12-08 03:29:08          NaN
        2       2014-12-08 03:29:08          0.0
        4       2015-02-09 00:10:01          5431253.0
```

Comment: What is this `Golden`? Any special class from a specific module/framework?

Comment: Hi sorry for the unclarity, Golden is what I named my data frame. The code is taking the time difference from the rows in the CREATED_ON column.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to sort your dataframe by `ID` and `CREATED_ON`.  Then you can group on `ID` and take the difference of the `CREATED_ON` column, which will give you a column of Timedelta objects.

```
# Set-up dataframe.
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ID': [2, 2, 4], 
     'CREATED_ON': [pd.Timestamp('2014-12-08 03:29:08'), 
                    pd.Timestamp('2014-12-08 03:29:08'), 
                    pd.Timestamp('2015-02-09 00:10:01')]})
# Sort dataframe on `ID` and `CREATED_ON`.
df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'CREATED_ON'])
# Assign new column based on group time differences.
df = df.assign(TimeDiff=df.groupby('ID')[['CREATED_ON']].transform(
    lambda group: group.diff()))
>>> df
           CREATED_ON  ID TimeDiff
0 2014-12-08 03:29:08   2      NaT
1 2014-12-08 03:29:08   2   0 days
2 2015-02-09 00:10:01   4      NaT
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am semi-new to Python and code in general. I will use your code for study purposes to gain further understanding of your logic.

Comment: What if I wanted time difference to be outputted on the first line rather than a NAT. Basically shifting values up one without messing up the df?